# Need insight into what this new error means?

Tags: c#, .net, debugging, error-handling

This is a .NET error:

```
Error Message: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
Error Source : mscorlib
```

This may be a bit cryptic-sounding but that's all I have to show. How to go about retracing what happened... I really need help on this, how can this come up if it didn't appear before, though the application was the same.
 thanks

Comment: What line of C# is this failing on? What operation are you performing at the time? It's impossible to know with that error message and no context what could be happening.

Comment: I don't believe that's all you have to show. Can't you at least trace it down to the crashing line of code?

Comment: The application was the same, but the data was probably different: where it used to say `True` or `False`, it now says something else.

Comment: Do you have access to the source code?  Can you debug/trace?  Can you reproduce the error?  Do you know what steps the user has to perform to reproduce the error?  All this error means is that somewhere in the code, it's looking for a string that's supposed to be either "true" or "false" or one of the very limited allowed string value (caps may vary) and it's receiving something else.  It could be as simple as a mis-spelled configuration value (Testing="flase" for example) or it could be from user input, a database, etc.  Unless you can find the offending line, you won't make much headway.

Comment: Most probably you are trying to parse a string that does not represent a valid boolean value.

Comment: More info on converting a string to a Boolean, including allowed values is covered here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/86hw82a3.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This error occurs when using [`bool.Parse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.parse.aspx) and the input into the method is not convertible to a boolean value of true/false.

For instance:

```
string testBool = "true";
bool validBool = bool.Parse(testBool);
// this passes fine

testBool = "asdf";
validBool = bool.Parse(testBool);
// Exception: String was not recognized as a valid Boolean.
```

If you're using .NET 4.0 or higher, you can use [`bool.TryParse()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.boolean.tryparse.aspx) instead; it will not throw the exception if it receives invalid input. Otherwise, wrap the statement in a `try / catch` to consume it.